# Finding equation of a plane passing though two lines given parametric equations

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I have two lines:

$$
a: \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=\lambda+2\mu \\
y=-\lambda+\mu \\
z=0\lambda-\mu \\
t=2\lambda+\mu
\end{array}
\right. \\
b: \left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=-p-3q \\
y=-p+2q \\
z=p \\
t=4p-q
\end{array}
\right.  
$$

How can I find equation of a plane passing those two lines?

Comment: I would try to calculate the intersection point of these lines

Comment: I suppose $(\lambda,\mu)$ and $(p,q)$ are barycentric coordinates on the lines, i.e. $\lambda+\mu=1$, $p+q=1$?

Comment: If you define a geometric object as
$\Gamma \rightarrow p = \lambda \vec u + \mu \vec v$ with $t = c_1 \lambda + c_2 \mu$ with $(\lambda, \mu, t) \in \Re^3$ this object will represent a plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $R^4$

with

$$
p_1 = \{1, -1, 0, 2\}\\
p_2 = \{2, 1, -1, 1\}\\
q_1 = \{-1, -1, 1, 4\}\\
q_2 = \{-3, -2, 0, -1\}
$$

we have

$$
L_1\rightarrow p=p_1\lambda+p_2\mu\\
L_2\rightarrow p=q_1\alpha+q_2\beta
$$

The plane equation is

$$
P \rightarrow < p - p_0, \vec v > = 0 \ \ \mbox{with} \ \ \vec v = \{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}
$$

If the lines are contained into the plane then

$$
< p_1\lambda+p_2\mu-p_0,\vec v > = 0\\
< q_1\alpha+q_2\beta-p_0,\vec v > = 0\\
$$

for all $\lambda,\mu,\alpha,\beta$ and the conditions are

$$
< p_1,\vec v > = 0\\
< p_2, \vec v > = 0\\
< q_1, \vec v > = 0\\
< q_2, \vec v > =0
$$

Solving for $\vec v$ we obtain $\vec v = 0$ hence no plane contains $L_1, L_2$